# СreateProcess из Win32Gui с ожиданием завершения

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, gui, процесс, консоль

Я новичек в win32gui и у меня пара вопросов:

Есть простое win32gui приложение с главным окном (и соответсвенно с message loop-ом). Его принцип работы мне известен.

1. Из него требуется запустить консольное приложение (например CreateProcess), определить когда оно зваершилось и получить его "exit code" в родительском win32gui. Не могли бы вы описать принцип, как сделать это правильно?
2. Также нужна следующая функция: во время работы консольного приложения нужна возможность из родительского приложения скрывать или показывать окно консольного приложения (при нажатие какой-нибудь кнопки, например). Как скрывать или показывать окно дочернего процесса во время исполнения?

Answer (score 0):

1) Запуск и ожидание процесса:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK;

TCHAR szProgramPath[] = _TEXT("C:\\Somewhere\\SomeProggie.exe");
if (!::CreateProcess(szProgramPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
  // Здесь обрабатывается ошибка, например так:
  DWORD dr = ::GetLastError();  // Получить код ошибки
  ProcessErrorAndQuit(dr);
}
::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);  // Это хендл обычно не нужен

::WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);  // Ждать завершения процесса

// Получить код завершения и закрыть хендл
DWORD dwExitCode;
::GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);  // Эта функция в принципе тоже может вернуть FALSE
::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
```

2) Окно дочернего процесса. Сам такое не делал, так что ответ теоретический

1. Получить ProcessID дочернего процесса
2. Найти главное окно по ProcessID
3. Вызвать функцию ShowWindow с соответствующий аргументом.

Как найти окно по ProcessID я отвечал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185312/how-to-start-an-exe-in-c-and-get-its-hwnd-window-handle-for-sending-messages/49194728#49194728).